# JSON Data not displaying on Ionic HTML Template

Tags: angularjs, json, cordova, web, ionic-framework

I have been trying to find the reason why my Ionic template is not displaying JSON data. I just started working and reading on ionic framework and angularjs.

please bear with my newbie questions;

1.) what is the error or cause why the json record is not displaying on the HTML?

2.) I have seen plenty of code samples where the Json codes is written on the controller.js instead on the services.js. Which one is standard and safe?

3.) I am having doubts regarding my json output, Can someone please confirm if the format is correct.

You help on this is really appreciated,. thanks in advance

here is my Console status:

```
Objectconfig: Objectdata: Array[1]0: Array[1]0: Array[1]0: 
Objectcapacity: "7"fuelcap: "120"
make: "Nissan"model: "LoadMaster II"platenumber: "TRG0122"
vehiclecode: "TRK0004"vehicleid: "8"wheelnumber: "10"
__proto__: Objectlength: 1__proto__: Array[0]
length: 1__proto__: Array[0]length: 1__proto__: Array[0]headers: (name)status: 200statusText: "OK"__proto__: Object
```

On my template/HTML file:

```
<ion-list id="vehicleInformation-list1" class=" " ng-repeat="recs in vehiclerecord">
   <ion-item id="vehicleInformation-list-item1" class="  ">Vehicle Model
      <span class="item-note">{{ recs.model }}</span>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

My Controller file:

```
.controller('vehicleInformationCtrl', function($scope, $http) { // TIP: Access Route Parameters for your page via $stateParams.parameterName
// var _this = this;
$http.get('http://myurlsample.com/webserve/').then(function(vehicleinfo    ) {
$scope.vehiclerecord = vehicleinfo.data;
console.log(vehicleinfo);
alert(JSON.stringify(vehicleinfo));
}).catch(function(vehicleinfo)
{
console.log(vehicleinfo);
});
 })
```

my Route.js file contains:

```
 .state('tabsController.vehicleInformation', {
    url: '/vehicleinfo',
    views: {
      'tab4': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/vehicleInformation.html',
        controller: 'vehicleInformationCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

Via Jsonview a record look like this;

```
[
[
[
{
vehicleid: "8",
platenumber: "TRG0122",
make: "Nissan",
model: "LoadMaster II",
capacity: "7",
fuelcap: "120",
wheelnumber: "10",
vehiclecode: "TRK0004"
}
]
]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your jsonview output correctly, it looks like there's a lot of nesting going on: 
`[[[{model: "LoadMaster II", ...}]]]`

The ng-repeat you have there will only work if the $scope.vehiclerecord looks like this:

`[{model: "LoadMaster II", ...}, ... ]`

Note that this is simply an array of objects with no nested arrays like your jsonview output.

So the solution is to play with vehicleinfo.data from the http response until you have only an array of objects. Based on the jsonview you have there, this would work:

```
$scope.vehiclerecord = vehicleinfo.data[0][0];
```